# Variable assignment from Object values in JS

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

What is the name or technical term of this form of variable declaration and assignment?

```js
const obj = {a: 3, b: 5}
const { a: s, b: t } = obj;
console.log(s,t) // 3 5
```

Comment: "destructuring"

Comment: With the documentation about that found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: ^The relevant section is call "object destructuring"

Comment: MDN calls the concept "destructuring assignment".